# Bluetooth not working Ubuntu 12.04 Fujitsu P771 Foxconn /Hon-hai 0489:e031

Tags: bluetooth

Ubuntu 12.04 does not recognize BT Foxconn /Hon-hai 0489:e031 on my Fujitsu Lifebook P771.
I went through several threads, but could not solve the problem.
Any possible solution?
Thanks, maurizio

Answer (score 0):

Generally Linux supports many devices out of the box. But yes, at this moment, this bluetooth adapter has problems in the way how the firmware loads. The kernel supports it and now it can even be recognized with new kernels (starting from 3.5.0.17). But the firmware doesn't load and you can't use it.

For new kernels as a temporary workaround you can do the following.

You run VirtualBox with Windows (Windows 7 is preferred) and then you share the device
with the guest machine. Check if it works. And if it works you just shutdown the guest, quit from VirtualBox and you would be able to use BT normally in Linux.

With Ubuntu 12.10, hopefully, it will start to at least recognize this adapter. You can 
check the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/863051

and mark it as "affects me".

With the last dist-upgrade this adapter started to recognized but is not working yet (i.e useless).

For now the only option is to wait.

More technical details here: http://marc.info/?l=linux-bluetooth&m=134704995714896&w=2

Here you can mark the bug as "affects me" so it get more attention https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1065400